# make an element a block element but only for print using bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two elements, which are shown next to each other horizontally, and I want to make them block elements when printing.

I have tried using .visible-print-block, but it makes the block invisible in the browser. How do I make the element a block element, but only when printing ?

thanks,

Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps create your own media query for this, for example

```
@media print {
    .print-block {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

See http://codepen.io/ckuijjer/full/VYaMxd/ for a codepen where you can test this

Comment: :) sounded like an easy one

Answer (score 1):

```
@media print {
    .yourElementsClass{
        display:block;
     }
}
```